# Mongodb difference in time is returning the current time

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57693a852956d5301b348a99"),
    "First_Name" : "Sri Ram",
    "Last_Name" : "Bandi",
    "Email" : "chinni001sriram@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [
        {
            "Class" : "facebook",
            "ID" : "1778142655749042",
            "Login_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:00:53.867Z"),
            "Logout_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:01:04.640Z"),
            "Duration" : null
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 1
}
```

This is my mongo data. and I want to set the `duration` as the difference of login and logout time. So, I executed the following query:

```
db.sessionData.update(
    { "Sessions.ID": "1778142655749042"},
    { $set:  {
        "Sessions.$.Duration": ISODate("Sessions.$.Logout_Time" - "Sessions.$.Login_Time")
        }
    }
)
```

But the result I'm getting is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57693a852956d5301b348a99"),
    "First_Name" : "Sri Ram",
    "Last_Name" : "Bandi",
    "Email" : "chinni001sriram@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [
        {
            "Class" : "facebook",
            "ID" : "1778142655749042",
            "Login_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:00:53.867Z"),
            "Logout_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:01:04.640Z"),
            "Duration" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:02:58.010Z")
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 1
}
```

and duration wast set to current time/date instead of the difference.

Comment: how u can perform arithmetic operation on date?

Comment: then how to get the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the aggregation framework to do the arithmetic operation using the **[`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/#exp._S_divide)** and **[`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract)** operators to give you the difference as duration in seconds. The formula is given by

```
Duration (sec) = (Logout_Time - Login_Time)/1000
```

The aggregation pipeline should give you a new field that has this computed value and then you can use the **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** cursor method on the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** result to iterate the documents in the result and update the collection.

The following example shows this:

```
db.sessionData.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "Sessions.ID" : "1778142655749042" } },
    { "$unwind": "$Sessions" },
    { "$match": { "Sessions.ID" : "1778142655749042" } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Duration": {
                "$divide": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$Sessions.Logout_Time", "$Sessions.Login_Time" ] },
                    1000
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function (doc) {
    db.sessionData.update(
        { "Sessions.ID": "1778142655749042", "_id": doc._id }, 
        { 
            "$set": { "Sessions.$.Duration": doc.Duration }
        }
    );
});
```

**Query results**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57693a852956d5301b348a99"),
    "First_Name" : "Sri Ram",
    "Last_Name" : "Bandi",
    "Email" : "chinni001sriram@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [ 
        {
            "Class" : "facebook",
            "ID" : "1778142655749042",
            "Login_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:00:53.867Z"),
            "Logout_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:01:04.640Z"),
            "Duration" : 10.773
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 1
}
```

Comment: can you provide the query if logout time is null innitially and I want it as the current time and get the duration simultaneously.. so matching criteria would be  where Sessions. id is 1778142655749042 and logout time is null

Comment: That would be a new question altogether, consider creating one for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950409/difference-in-date-objects-is-not-returning-the-appropriate-interval