# Referencing the document attribute to update another in mongo update query

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57693a852956d5301b348a99"),
    "First_Name" : "Sri Ram",
    "Last_Name" : "Bandi",
    "Email" : "chinni001sriram@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [
        {
            "Class" : "facebook",
            "ID" : "1778142655749042",
            "Login_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:00:53.867Z"),
            "Logout_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-21T13:01:04.640Z"),
            "Duration" : null
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 1
}
```

This is my mongo data and I want to set the logout time as current time and "duration" as the difference of login and logout time simultaneously. So I executed the following query:

```
collection.update(
    {
        "Sessions.ID": 1778142655749042, 
        "Sessions.Logout_Time": null
    },
    {  
        "$set": {
            "Sessions.$.Logout_Time": new Date(),
            "Sessions.$.Duration": new Date(new Date() - "$Sessions.$.Login_Time"),
        }, 
    }
);
```

But the result I'm getting is setting logout time as current time but duration is set to 'NaN'.

Answer (score 0):

**Mongo doesn't support referring to current object in update**

So what you can do is :

```
  db.collection.find( { "Sessions.ID": 1778142655749042, "Sessions.Logout_Time": null
    }).forEach(function(doc){

       for(var session in doc.Sessions){
           if(!session.Logout_Time){
               session.Logout_Time =  new Date();
               session.Duration = new Date(new Date() - doc.Login_Time");
             }

       }

db.collection.save(doc);

});
```

Comment: no it didn't work, here is the output :       {
 "_id" : ObjectId("576a2bf55b0fc2f00194f2cd"),
 "First_Name" : "Sri Ram",
 "Last_Name" : "Bandi",
 "Email" : "chinni001sriram@gmail.com",
 "Sessions" : [
  {
   "Class" : "facebook",
   "ID" : "1778142655749042",
   "Login_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-22T06:11:01.030Z"),
   "Logout_Time" : null,
   "Duration" : null
  }
 ],
 "Count" : 1,
 "Logout_Time" : ISODate("2016-06-22T06:11:08.386Z"),
 "Duration" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}

Comment: The problelm would only be within foreach loop, where you can tune this accordingly. Cahnge this a bit according to the schema you are using. This is the only way you can achieve this. Try once more. Also update my answer with updated query if that works

Comment: Even i am trying to update my answer. I guess the required keys are within sessions array. I wrote the answer just for information purpose